# MPMediaPickerController does't show after playing Youtube video in WebView

Tags: iphone, ios

MPMediaPickerController works normally but after playing youtube video in webview 
[self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES]; 
does not shows MPMediaPickerController 
im using this code for playing youtube video

```
 - (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {  
      NSString* embedHTML = @"\ 
      <html><head>\ 
      <style type=\"text/css\">\ 
      body {\ 
          background-color: transparent;\ 
      color: white;\ 
      }\ 
      </style>\ 
      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\ 
      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \ 
      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\ 
      </body></html>";  
      NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width,    frame.size.height];  
      demoWebView.hidden = NO;
      [demoWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil]; }
```

Comment: I had a problem a while ago afer playing a youtube video i would recieve a level 2 memory warning and then the viewcontroller dissapeard, are you sure you are not recieving a memory warning?

Comment: no my app does not recieves memory warning

Comment: but a have this warning  No copy of YouTubePlugIn.webplugin/YouTubePlugIn found locally, reading from memory on remote devic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using presentModalViewController with a UIWebView that was playing YouTube video, now a'm using navigation controller and everything works properly.